# SQL select all items with the same column values

Tags: sql, where-clause

So here is the output of my current query:

| ID | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 871 | 1 | 1 |
| 646 | 1 | Null |
| 1223 | 8 | 1 |
| 1223 | 8 | 2 |
| 1223 | 8 | 3 |
| 1224 | 1 | 1 |
| 1224 | 1 | 2 |

What I'd like to do is only keep the rows which satisfy the following:

- Col2 is Null; or
- ID+Col1 == Col2 for one of the rows with the same ID, e.g., the bottom two rows are not included because the second from the bottom Col1==Col2 and the bottommost is not included because the ID and Col1 match the second from the bottom in which Col1==Col2.

For this table, the only rows which should remain are the ones with IDs 646 and 1223.

I tried the following `where` clause, however it's improperly retaining the bottommost row: `(Col2 is null and Col1 is not null) or (Col1 <> Col2)`. Any help appreciated!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: _Specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
    select *
    from my_table
    where (Col2 is null and Col1 is not null) 
     or (id not in (select id 
                    from my_table
                    where Col1 = Col2)
         )
```

db-fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xmufn82r9W522YiKKh1Qka/0

Answer (score 0):

I would firstly mark the IDs and col1 of bad rows, then filter the table using these marked rows:

```sql
WITH marked AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Col1
FROM table
WHERE Col1 = Col2 OR Col1 IS NULL AND Col2 IS NULL
)
SELECT ID
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN marked t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.Col1 = T2.ColId
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic can be applied with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.Col2 IS NULL
   OR NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 
     FROM tablename t2
     WHERE t2.Col1 = t2.Col2 AND t2.ID = t1.ID
   );
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6e88077f3fe8d718233463c21b86cafb).